# TabBar to go to initial Screen using ReactNavigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I use TabNavigator from ReactNavigation. First Tab shows Home. Home has StackNavigator too. Only if navigate from Home to others pages from the Stack, then clicking on tab Home it will not bring back to the first screen of the stack.

Here is the code:

```
const MainNavigator =
      TabNavigator(
      {
        Home: {screen: MainStackNavigator},
        Expressions : {screen : expressions},
      }, {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
      }
      );

  const MainStackNavigator =
  StackNavigator({
  WelcomeSlides: {screen: WelcomeSlides},
  Home: { screen: FirebaseReactNative },
  Details: { screen: WordItem }
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send back to `Home` screen:

```
Home: {screen: MainNavigator},
```